# using void pointer in swap function

Tags: c, pointers, swap, void

I have a swap function like so:

```
void swap(int i, int j, void* arr[])
{
    void *temp;
    temp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[j];
    arr[j] = temp;
}
```

I call swap in main like so:

```
main()
{
    int arr[8] = {4,7,9,2,6,7,8,1};
    void *ptr = arr;
    swap(0, 1, ptr);
    int k;
    for (k=0; k<8; k++)
        printf("%d ", arr[k]);
}
```

Now, the swap seems to work fine, however instead of swapping 1 value with another, it is swapping 2 values with another 2 values. For example, when I do swap(0, 1, ptr), i get the array

```
9,2,4,7,6,7,8,1
```

when I should be getting:

```
7,4,9,2,6,7,8,1
```

Instead of swapping 4 and 7, it is swapping 4,7 with 9,2. Why is it doing this?

Comment: it looks like you are on a 64 bit system that gives you 64 bits by default, try a printf of sizeof arr[0] and sizeof int to verify, you can pass an extra parameter for size and use a char[size] buffer with memcpy or just use an xor swap if you verify they are different addresses (in other words don't swap 1 and 1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`swap()` is treating the array as an array of pointers, but the actual array being passed is an array of type `int`. Apparently, your system is such that a pointer is the size of two `int`s, and so everytime it swaps a "pointer", it's really swapping two integers.

You would need your swap routine to be something like this:

```
void swap(int i, int j, int arr[])
{
    int temp;
    temp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[j];
    arr[j] = temp;
}
```

Comment: which then might segfault if `i`/`j` were > `size/2`